# Yii and ActiveRecord Group by Count

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, highcharts

I'm relatively new to Yii and would like to experiment a little. I have looked around all over the internet and I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. I have mastered the basics of Yii but I think that this is quite advanced or I'm just being stupid.

I have a MYSQL table with a list of items bought. This table has CUSTOMER_ID as the main field with each CUSTOMER_ID possibly having more than one ITEM's. I would like to do a count BY TRANSACTION_ID and then assess as in line with the following logic:

```
1) IF myCount = 1 then businessType = 'New'; 
2) If myCount = 2 then businessType = 'Repeat'; 
3) If myCount > 2 then businessType = '2+ Repeat';
```

I'm not sure where and how would be the best way to do this however? afterSave()?? Or in the controller? I have to get the result of the query into a GROUPED CActiveDataProvider object as I feed this data into Highcharts.

My grouping needs to look as follows (From lowest level to highest) :

```
businessType->store->item->{Count(ITEM), SUM(Cost)}
```

I am unfortunately not able to add a variable to the table and would really like to achieve this without having to. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to do this you will need to use CDbCriteria to group results in a CActiveDataProvider. See here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#group-detail. You'll need to implement it in your controller something like this;

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'the columns to select, and maybe SUM()';
$criteria->group = 'columns to group by';
etc
etc

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('model name', $criteria);
```

Without knowing the exact implementation of your database I can only give a general example, but you should find something like this works for you. I'm not sure how to get the grouping your talking about as `businessType->store->item->{Count(ITEM), SUM(Cost)}`, as you haven't shown your database and model structure.

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for this. This will work for part of the problem but will not solve the per customer count (New, Repeat)...Any idea on this?

Comment: You can do this directly in mysql, assuming that mycount is the transaction count from your query; SELECT CASE mycount WHEN 1 THEN 'new' WHEN 2 THEN 'repeat' WHEN mycount>2 THEN '2+ repeat'

Comment: Thank you so much Joe. I tried up voting but I don't have a high enough rep. I used your suggestion together with an OUTER JOIN.